# How to store a sequence of numbers whose size is not know in advance in C?

Tags: c, input, malloc

I am working on a standard deviation program in C and am having difficulty with the intended input.

I must accept an unknown number of floats and I am not sure how to go about storing them and allocating memory for them.

Sample input:

```
82.5
1000.6699
10
11.11
-45
#
```

Any advice is appreciated.

New user, sorry for little mistakes

Comment: you could create a linked list of integers where each node is defined as `struct node { int n; struct node *next;};`

Comment: see `realloc` for increasing buffer sizes

Comment: its not clear if its command line (argv) input or input from a file.

Comment: It is mathematically possible to compute the standard deviation of a list of numbers without storing them. The math can be done in a single pass over the numbers, if you know what information you need to accumulate for them.

Comment: Never post a picture, or worse just a link to one, when it's just text. Add the text instead.

Comment: (0) You say you must accept “an unknown number of integers”, but your sample data shows non-integers. You **must** clarify the problem statement. (1) You say you need to compute the standard deviation of a sequence of numbers and ask about storing them in memory, but it is not necessary to store numbers in order to calculate their standard deviation (per my comment above). Does the project assignment **explicitly** require you to store the numbers in memory? (2) You say your program must accept input using `argv` but also say the input is separated by newlines. Arguments passed by `argv`…

Comment: … usually do not include newlines. Usually, newlines appear in input from file streams. Which way are you supposed to get the input from? Is all the input coming from `argv`? In what format? Or are the numbers being read from standard input? Or from a file? Is there anything in `argv`? Perhaps a number of numbers or the name of a file to read from?

Comment: Going back to (1), do you have a formula for computing the standard deviation of a list of numbers? What is it?

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE].

Comment: Sorry for errors, Just looking for a way to store and allocate input that I don't know the size of.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Could you elaborate on how the math could be done in a single pass without storing the numbers?

Comment: @Singh: Do you have a formula for computing the standard deviation of a list of numbers? What is it? Does your project assignment explicitly require you to store numbers in memory?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I do have the formula. The project assignment did not require us to store numbers, but it was implied to us in the instructions. I solved the problem using linked lists and using malloc to store each node.

Comment: @Singh: What is the formula?

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate an array to hold your values, and you can use `realloc()` to grow that array.

Because `realloc()` has some overhead, I would probably allocate enough memory for, maybe, 16 values. And when you fill it, then resize it to hold up to an additional 16 values and so on. This way, your code doesn't resize the memory for every value.

Comment: Who is downvoting answers without commenting what the problem is?

Answer (score -1):

There're really only two ways. The first is to define a *struct*:

```
typedef struct {
    int value;
    element* next;
} element;
```

Then, you have what's called a linked list. You can access the nth element by iterating through the linked `element` structs, and you know you've reached the end when the `element.next` is a null pointer (and `element->next` is a SegFault or returns nonsense).

The second way is to "play it safe" and define a fixed-length array that is the maximum size you will need.  Something like:

```
int my_array[65535];
```

This is advantageous because arrays are much faster than linked lists (you don't have to iterate to access the nth element) but if the array length is highly variable this can allocate much more memory than is necessary. It's up to you which you prefer.

Comment: A 3rd choice is to only store the one just read.  A list is not needed in OP's case.

Comment: (0) There are not really only two ways. (1) There is no need for a linked list for this simple problem, and it would be wasteful. (2) An array of fixed “maximum” size does not satisfy the problem requirement of accepting an unknown number of inputs.